# How can one adapt to JS frameworks and libraries?

Tags: javascript

I don't know if I am asking this in the correct forum, but if not, please relocate it for me.

I am more than comfortable and skilled with vanilla JS, including but not limited to ES6 standards. However, when it comes to picking up a framework or library or NodeJS, I become dumbfounded and confused. I cannot seem to grasp it, and it has become overhelming for me. I have tried courses and reading articles with no success. I feel they just touch up on the bare minimum for absolute beginners.

Any ideas on how I can master (or at least become intermediate with) frameworks like React, npm packages such as webpack and babel, and the nodeJS runtime?

Comment: It sounds like you have trouble working with others' code. The best way to get comfortable is learning how to read and understand code/documentation *quickly*. This comes with experience and *lots* of dedicated practice. It's a transcendence for a developer when he/she can leverage the work of others. There is *never* a tool, written from someone else, that does *exactly* what you want, how you want. Time, patience, and application is the only way; getting involved in SO is a great start.

Comment: Unfortunaly SO is a QA forum where the post should point particular problems. This is not only too broad but a little bit opinion based. I recommend you to read other people code to get used to it. Adapt frameworks is usually not good, you can end up making everything from the start. Your code should be flexible enough to include or adapt a good designed library. However you should not confuse the language with the particular variants for particular usages that it can have. NodeJS for example is just JS to the sever side, it varies a bit but its the same JS.